# Unable to configure Nginx as a reverse proxy for elasticsearch on another server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to use Kibana on a server A to access elasticsearch on a server B.
elasticsearch is protected with a basic auth authentication on server B.

Kibana is also protected with basic authentication (and the same password) on server A.

I'm using [this](https://gist.github.com/hlassiege/179866de70c3d8d992ab) configuration (inspired from [here](https://github.com/johnhamelink/ansible-kibana/blob/master/templates/nginx.conf.j2))

I'm just trying the redirection by typing the following address and I get a error 500:

- http://A.com/es/_search

In the log I have:

> 2014/06/01 16:45:55 [error] 3721#0: *1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/es/_search", client: 192.168.50.1, server: A.com, request: "GET /es/_search HTTP/1.1", host: "A.com"

Any idea what could be wrong ?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the configs.

Comment: why so many rewrites are needed? have you tried default kibana config?  https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/blob/master/sample/nginx.conf

Comment: I've read this settings but at first I thought it was not correct for my use case. But I've tried just now and it works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#
# Nginx proxy for Elasticsearch + Kibana
#
# In this setup, we are password protecting the saving of dashboards. You may
# wish to extend the password protection to all paths.
#
# Even though these paths are being called as the result of an ajax request, the
# browser will prompt for a username/password on the first request
#
# If you use this, you'll want to point config.js at http://FQDN:80/ instead of
# http://FQDN:9200
#
server {
  listen                *:80 ;

  server_name           kibana.myhost.org;
  access_log            /var/log/nginx/kibana.myhost.org.access.log;

  location / {
    root  /usr/share/kibana3;
    index  index.html  index.htm;
  }

  location ~ ^/_aliases$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
  }
  location ~ ^/.*/_aliases$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
  }
  location ~ ^/_nodes$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
  }
  location ~ ^/.*/_search$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
  }
  location ~ ^/.*/_mapping {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
  }

  # Password protected end points
  location ~ ^/kibana-int/dashboard/.*$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
    limit_except GET {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
      auth_basic "Restricted";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana.myhost.org.htpasswd;
    }
  }
  location ~ ^/kibana-int/temp.*$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
    limit_except GET {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
      auth_basic "Restricted";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana.myhost.org.htpasswd;
    }
  }
}
```